How to see if an array includes a nested array with specific values?
How to correctly iterate through shipMisses array to see if it contains the nested array with the specific values [2, 4] (the dName variabe)?
Here is my code:
shipMisses.includes(dName) // shipMisses = [[0, 1], [2, 4]]
                           // dName = [2, 4]


The particular nested array, or any nested array that has these values?

You can use the callback function for comparison. Here is an example:
const shipMisses = [[0, 1], [2, 4]];
const dName = [2, 4];

// Using Array.prototype.some() to iterate and check if any array matches dName
const containsDName = shipMisses.some(arr => arr[0] === dName[0] && arr[1] === dName[1]);

console.log(containsDName); // true



You can use the Array#some element to check if at least one element is:

an array, and
equal to the given array (the JSON.stringify method is one way to check)



const shipMisses = [[0, 1], [2, 4]];
const dName = [2, 4];

const arrayFound = shipMisses.some(
  a => 
  //check if the element is an array
  Array.isArray(a) 
  //and
  && 
  //check if it equals dName
  JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(dName)
);

console.log( arrayFound );



Using the same array method you may also check by iteration to see if at least one element is:

an array, and
has the same length as the given array, and
every element of this array equals the corresponding element in the given array



const shipMisses = [[0, 1], [2, 4], [6, 8, 0, 9]];
const dName = [6, 8, 0, 9];

const arrayFound = shipMisses.some(
  a => 
  //check if the element is an array
  Array.isArray(a) 
  //and
  && 
  //check if lengths are equal
  a.length === dName.length
  //add
  &&
  //check if each element of a equals the corresponding element of dName
  a.every((b,i) => b === dName[i])
);

console.log( arrayFound );



